# Deriving the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n} \left(\hat{\beta_{IV}} - \hat{\beta_{OLS}} \right)$

Tags: random-variables, asymptotics, normal-distribution, variance

We have the following
[Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddA6d.png)

I am not sure about how to derive the asympotic distribution of
$\sqrt{n} \left(\hat{\beta_{IV}} - \hat{\beta_{OLS}} \right)$.
The expression $\sqrt{n} \left(\hat{\beta_{IV}} - \hat{\beta_{OLS}} \right)$ is given by
$$\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^N z_i^{\prime} x_i\right)^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^N z_i^{\prime} u_i-\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^{\prime} x_i\right)^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^{\prime} u_{i}$$
Then the left part converges to a normal distribution and the right side as well, using central limit theorem, weak law of large numbers and continuous mapping theorem, and slutsky theorem. How do I proceed from here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the subscripted things under the summations: the $x'_i$ and so on? Which are random?, which are independent?, which are given constants?, and so on.

Comment: I added a picture with more information to the post